# lavinshtein distance with dictionary

Tags: dictionary, anagram, edit-distance

How to advance edit distance with operation **take an anagram** of the existing word. every interim step must be a word from a list of words .

Comment: It might not be possible

Answer (score 3):

The standard technique for anagrams is to store words in canonical sorted order, e.g. "Banana" becomes "aaabnn". Do that for all valid words, then consider [Levenshtein distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between *those*. You will want to map from canonical to a valid set, e.g. `valid['dgo'] = {'dog', 'god'}`

Take a look at `tail /usr/share/dict/words` if you need a set of valid words.